# APS $\eta$-invariant and spin-Ising TQFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory, ising-model, topological-insulators, quantum-anomalies

I am interested in the relation between the Atiyah-Patodi-Singer-$\eta$ invariant and spin topological quantum field theory. In the paper [Gapped Boundary Phases of Topological Insulators via Weak Coupling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04251) by Seiberg and Witten, they presented such relation between the two.

Let the $3+1$ dimensional manifold $X$ be the world volume of a topological insulator. Its bounday $W$ is a $2+1$ dimensional manifold. Let $\chi$ be a massless Dirac fermion on the bounday manifold $W$. Then, integrating out the boundary fermion

$$\int_{W}d^{3}x\,i\bar{\chi}D \!\!\!\!/\,\chi\,, $$

where $D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+iA_{\mu}$, one has the partition function

$$\mathcal{Z}=|\det(iD)|e^{-i\pi\eta(A)/2}.$$

So far, this is just the standard parity anomaly in odd dimensions.

On page 35, the authors claimed that the factor $\Phi=e^{-i\pi\eta/2}$ is actually the partition function of a topological quantum field theory, called spin-Ising TQFT. The name comes from the fact that it is related with the 2D Ising model of CFT. The authors explained that this is due to the [Free-Dai theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405012).

I don't really understand much from the paper of [Freed-Dai theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405012) because of its heavy mathematics. But from my understanding, it is saying that the $\eta$ invariant is some kind of topological invariant and cobordism invariant, which satisfies the gluing and surgery axioms of TQFT. Thus, the factor $\Phi=e^{-i\pi\eta/2}$ can be treated as the partition function of some TQFT.

Now the question is why this TQFT is the so-called spin-Ising TQFT. The authors claim that the partition function of the spin-Ising TQFT should be of modulus $1$ because the $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ chiral ring generated by the field $\psi$ (from the 2D Ising model $\left\{1,\sigma,\psi\right\}$) has only one representation.

***Question 1: Why does the fact that the chiral algebra has one representation makes its partition function being of modulus $1$?***

The authors then showed an example, taking the manifold $W$ to be $S^{2}\times S^{1}$, that the partition function of the corresponding spin-Ising TQFT is $\pm 1$, which is indeed a phase. Then, by Freed-Dai theorem, they claimed that in general the partition function of a spin-Ising TQFT should be $\Phi=e^{-i\pi\eta/2}$.

***I don't really understand much from the paper of [Freed-Dai theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405012). Could anyone please enlighten me on how one should apply that theorem to this case?***

The authors explained in the following that if $W$ has a boundary $\Sigma$, then the product of the path integral of the chiral fermion $\psi$ on $\Sigma$ and the factor $\Phi$ is smooth and well-defined because of the Freed-Dai theorem.

***However, in our case, the manifold $W$ itself is the boundary of the $3+1$-manifold $X$, and so $W$ has no bounday at all. How should one understand the explanation provided by the authors?***

Answer (score 3):

1. For 3-manifolds which are circle fibrations of 2-manifolds, this follows from the fact that any such partition function may be computed as trace of an operator on the Hilbert space of the 2-manifold. More generally however, we need to understand how to cut up our 3-manifolds and compute the partition function of the pieces. Using a Heegaard splitting for instance, we can express the partition function on any 3-manifold as an inner product between two states in the Hilbert space of a surface. The states are associated to the path integral on the two handle-bodies on either side of the splitting, and one can show that they are normalized by considering the path integral on the double $M \cup \bar M$ of either handle-body, which equals 1 by reflection positivity. Since the Hilbert space of states is one-dimensional on the separating surface, it follows that the partition function is a phase. You can think of the Dai-Freed theorem as giving an explicit representation of the states associated to these handle-bodies. This is a version of the usual TQFT-RCFT correspondence where conformal blocks of the RCFT give states of the TQFT.
2. There are equivalent formulations of this $\eta$ invariant which are useful for different purposes. It is true you can use the APS index theorem to express $e^{i\eta/2}$ of a *closed* 3-manifold as an integral over a bounding 4-manifold. This is useful to show its quantization properties. On the other hand, $e^{i\eta/2}$ has an intrinsically 3-dimensional definition which is the spectral asymmetry of the associated Dirac operator. Dai-Freed tell you what happens when you try to consider this definition on a 3-manifold with boundary. You cannot use the 4-dimensional definition in this case (which is manifestly gauge-invariant), and so there is room for some gauge non-invariance.

Answer (score 1):

I will recapitulate the argument of the authors. I can not, however prove their statements. I hope this helps anyhow.

The authors write

[image]

Let's recapitulate the argument. Take a three-manifold $W$ with boundary $\Sigma$. Then, they say, the Dai-Freed theorem declares that the following is well defined:

$$ \exp(-i \pi \eta(W) /2) Z_\psi(\Sigma) \ ,$$

where $Z_\psi(\Sigma)$ is the partition function of the Ising spin-CFT on the 2-manifold $\Sigma$. This means that, for the special case that $\Sigma = \{ \}$, the empty manifold, $\exp(-i \pi \eta(W) /2)$ is well-defined and is associated to the Ising spin-CFT. This is a statement purely about the $\eta$-invariant of a closed three-manifold $W$ and thus holds regardless whether $W$ is a boundary or not.

For the questions about the representations: It doesn't seem to me that this is what they are claiming. They start with some the $\eta$-invariant, and then they show how this is related to this spin-CFT.

Comment: Do you think that the partition $\mathcal{Z}_{\psi}(\Sigma)$ is related with the holomorphic sector of the free Majorana fermion in $2D$? If this were true, then I think $\mathcal{Z}_{\psi}(\Sigma)$ is just $\det(i\bar{\partial})$. The motivation behind my statement is that I found that the Ising model looks like a sum over the even spin structures of the free Majonara fermion on a torus.

Comment: Note that $Z_\psi(\Sigma)$ is the partition function on a two-dimensional spin manifold. That is, the spin structure is part of the data used to define the model.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. The authors said that the Ising model sums over spin structures of the spin-Ising model.

Comment: No, the (non-spin) Ising CFT is where one sums over spin structures. For the spin Ising CFT the spin structure is fixed.

Comment: Yes it is what I just said.

Comment: oh, right, i misread your comment. Well but then i don't understand the question. The authors say that one has to multiply the partition function of a chiral 2d fermion to the $\eta$ invariant. This chiral fermion is Majorana (they mention this in the text).

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that they already said that it is weyl-majorana fermion. I think it should be free weyl-majorana fermion. Do you think it is true?

Comment: That is what i (and they) say.